# Changing category ID's / Resetting Magento ID Count

Tags: category

I'm trying to change the category ID's for my Magento store. Or figure out a way to 'reset' the Magento ID count, as I'm fairly sure that it adds on to the ID count whenever I import categories.

EG. The category should be :81 (as it is on the live site), but it's actually :20046 (after importing categories).

Hence when I import products, it does not go to the correct Category folder.

FYI: I'm creating a prototype backup site from a live site.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are just creating a replica then why not do it via DB export -> import. This way you wouldn't have to bother about IDs.

Comment: Good idea. Just copied the entire live site database onto the prototypes, changed the local.xml to call it and it's worked a charm. Cheers

Comment: @Prateek you should add this comment as an answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: @AndreasvonStudnitz, Didn't receive any notification about the comment saying that my idea helped him to solve the problem. There should be some sort of notification in SE for all previous commentators even they are not mentioned in the comment. Thanks for pointing this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just creating a replica then why not do it via DB export -> import. This way you wouldn't have to bother about IDs